# Where can you place a portal on a moving surface in Portal 2?

Tags: portal-2

I've heard there are places in Portal 2 where it is possible to place a portal on a moving surface without the portal disappearing? What chamber is this in, and is it possible that I played through it, or is it a required mechanism of the game?

Comment: It was [demonstrated on YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CDNrPU06c6c) that this is possible using sv_allow_mobile_portals.

Comment: I think they didn't want players to interact directly with moving portals. The people behind Portal 2 know what they are doing and if moving portals were a good idea they would probably have already used them in Portal 2.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Chapter 5 - Area 3

> When you have to cut the tubes of the neurotoxin generator.

But I think it's the only place in the game. Correct me if I'm wrong!

Comment: @Juan Manuel: Thank you! I was looking for that functionality.

Comment: +1 simply for the invisible text.  How DID you find that out?

Comment: Found out what? The invisible text? It's because of Juan's edit. You have to put >! before the text you want to hide.